# Scalar product of Gaussian random vector with projection matrix is chi-squared

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

We define the $n$ chi-square random variable this way : if $Z \sim N(0,I_n)$ is multivariate Gaussian random vector, then $\lVert Z \rVert ^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2$ (sum of $n$ standard gaussian RV squared) is said to have $n$ chi-square random variable.

Let $H$ be a projection matrix of rank $k \leq n$ and $Z \sim N(0,I_n)$. Show that $Z^T HZ$ is a $k$ chi-square random variable.

$Z^T HZ$ is a 1D random variable so its squared norm is equal to $\lvert Z^T HZ \rvert^2$. We want to show that it can be written as the sum of $k$ standard gaussian RV squared. Since $H$ is a projection matrix of rank $k$, it can be written as $H=U^T D U$ with $D=diag(1,\dots,1,0,\dots,0)$ with k ones and $n-k$ zeros (because rank $k$). It gives $Z^T HZ=(UZ)^TD (UZ)$ and this gives $$\lvert Z^T H Z\rvert =\bigg\lvert \sum_{i=1}^k(UZ)_i^2\bigg\rvert = \sum_{i=1}^k(UZ)_i^2$$

Now I know that $U$ is orthogonal so $UZ \sim N(0,I_n)$ and hence $\lvert Z^T H Z\rvert$ is the sum of $k$ standard gaussian RV squared. However, we are interested in $\lvert Z^T H Z\rvert^2=\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^k(UZ)_i^2\bigg)^2$ which a really something else to treat. How can I deal with this ?

Comment: And in fact if we take $H=I_n$, then $Z^TZ=\sum (Z_i)^2$ (which is n chi squared) but then its squared norm would be the square of that n chi squared ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Have a look at Cochran's Theorem, it might help... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem

Comment: But why are you considering the square of $Z^T H Z$ in the first place? $Z^T H Z$ is not univariate normal !

Comment: @stubbornatom Yes I realized my silly mistake right after writing the post but I spent too much time typing to delete it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Z^T H Z$ is not univariate normal so it does not make sense to consider its norm; as said by @StubbornAtom in comment section.